# Pokemon Go closes on its own?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I have an Android phone and I recently downloaded the Pokemon Go app. Every time I open the app and get to the start screen where it shows the picture of Gyarados the pop-up box comes up and asks that the user be aware of their surroundings. Everytime I click the okay box, the app freezes up a little bit and goes back to the home screen on its own without me doing anything. None of the people I have talked to have had this issue. I'm just wondering if there's an issue with my app, my phone, or if it's just the servers?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone already?  It sounds like a hard app crash. (where it drops the user back to the OS)  It could also be a bad install and you just need to reinstall?

Comment: Yes I reinstalled and updated the game

Comment: What's the specific model and maker of the phone? Also is it a rooted phone or do you have developer options enabled? These could cause an issue with the game.